# Notification when My.Computer.Audio.Play with AudioPlayMode.Background is done?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, audio

This (VB.NET) snippet plays the sound file held in sFile synchronously:

```
My.Computer.Audio.Play(sFile, AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
```

As it happens, my app has better things to do than to wait for its end, so I'd like it to play the file asynchronously:

```
My.Computer.Audio.Play(sFile, AudioPlayMode.Background)
```

While happily calculating stuff, the app might decide to play another sound, so I place it in a queue, to be played when the file currently playing asynchronously has finished.

But: how do I determine that the file has been played? `Audio.Play` does not seem to be an instantiated object, so how can I possibly catch a "Done" event of some sort?

Comment: You are using a BackgroundWorker which has a Progress Event.  The progress Event can use a state object to pass info to main thread.   See : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: And yet another toy to play with, thank you. I will use its `IsBusy` property, though.

Comment: IsBusy has to be polled while Progress is an event.  If you are playing more than one song he progress event can report the next song at same time.